# The overflow menu is not showing in Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-menu

[image]

I'm following the simple Tutorial, The problem is its not showing overflow menu in Android 4.2.2. And if I press hardware menu button its showing listed menus.

xml code:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/add_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_emo_laugh"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Emo Laugh"
  >
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_emo_tongue"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Emo TOngue"
    >
</item>
```

Comment: If your device has a menu button then overflow icon will not appear on screen. It only appears for devices which does not have menu button.

Comment: @TalhaMir I tried with disabling hardware keys. This will not solve the issue??

Answer (score 5):

@TalhaMir  right. If you want to be sure that overflow menu always visible you can use this workaround

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:id="@+id/capture" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_capture" android:showAsAction="always"/>
       <item android:id="@+id/location" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_location" android:showAsAction="always"/>
       <item android:showAsAction="always" android:icon="@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_dark">
           <menu>
               <item android:id="@+id/terms_of_service" android:title="@string/ab_terms_of_service"/>
               <item android:id="@+id/privacy_policy" android:title="@string/ab_privacy_policy"/>
               <item android:id="@+id/help" android:title="@string/ab_help"/>
           </menu>
       </item>
   </menu>
```

or you can use this hack in `onCreate` method of your `Application` class

```
private void getOverflowMenu() {

     try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if(menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But this hack breaks compatibility and as I know doesn't work with Action Bar Sherlock

Comment: I created new Emulator, Galaxy Nexus. Its working fine now without including the above codes!

Comment: It depends on hardware menu button. If new device emulator haven't them this will work. But I prefer to use workaround from first snippet for better consistency on all devices